# Custom Checkbox changes its size when isChecked is true Android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have an single choice ExpandableListView with a custom checkbox defined by a Drawable I created in the Android Asset Studio.

For some reason, when the checkbox is checked it looks smaller than when it is not. I already checked if I made a mistake with the size of the images and they all have the same size. (disabled or enabled).

Here's the code of my custom checkbox:

drawable/custom_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_success_enabled" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_accept_disabled" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_accept_disabled" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_success_enabled" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```

My drawable/ic_success_enabled & disabled are:

[image: enabled]

[image: disabled]

The rows for each element in the ExpandableListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_one_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/one_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one_item_row_image"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/akdemia_0_black" />

    <com.akdemia.application.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/one_item_row_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_icon_iphone" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/one_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/akdemia_checkbox"
        android:button="@null"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is a screen shot of the ExpandableListView, where you guys can see the problem: (All the orange rectangles where added on purpose, just ignore them)

[image: screenshot]

Hope anyone can help me with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your checkbox a layout width and height like this:

```
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
```

Comment: Geez... that was awkward haha, never thought of checking the width and height. Thanks! This solved the problem.

Comment: No problem, it's always the small things ;)